# Jump to a spefific div if key pressed on keyboard

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a .aspx Page.

What iam trying to do is, that if i press "T" on the Keyboard, the side should jump to a specific div. Is there a way resolve that?

I tried with javascript:

```
document.body.onkeypressed
```

But always getting Errors. Can some help? Thanks

SOLUTION:

```
 function shortcut(event) {
            if (event.keyCode) {
                keycode = event.keyCode;
            }
            else {
                keycode = event.which;
            }
            switch (String.fromCharCode(keycode)) {
                case ("1"):
                    document.getElementById('TblVerfuegbareDienstleistungen').scrollIntoView();  
                    break;
                case ("2"):
                    document.getElementById('TblReservierungen').scrollIntoView();
                    break;
            }
        }

        onload = function() {
            document.body.onkeypress = function() {
                shortcut(window.event);
            }
        }
```

Comment: So once you determine the key pressed, then what do you do?

Comment: Show your code and tell us what error you're getting.

Comment: show html and the code you tried

Comment: Look at jQuery `keypress()` API  http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: @DavidCorbin Why suggest `jQuery` for such a small task like this?

Comment: Since jQuery is good for a lot of things you can use is for anything else in your page and have great documentation and examples for it.

Comment: Just send the focus to the desired `div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this example with jQuery.

```
$('body').on('keydown',function(e){
      if(e.which==84){
          $(window).scrollTop($('#divID').offset().top);
          $("#divID").focus();
      }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/65gLv/2/)**

Example with JavaScript

```
window.onkeypress = function() {
    var x;      
    x=event.which;

   keychar=String.fromCharCode(x);
   if(keychar == "t" || keychar == "T") {
       //window.location.hash ="#div4";    // first time work but then scroll to top and hit 'T' it is not work.
       document.getElementById('div3').scrollIntoView();
   }
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2yH4f/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help! I updated my Code. Can you have a look? Is that a good solution? It works like charm i already tested? You know ik that works on all browser? FF, IE 9, 10, 11 ?

Comment: @Parks I tested jQuery example with all browser its works fine but Java Script example not working on FF.

Answer (score -1):

```
<javascript>
   window.onkeypress = function() {
      var x;
      if(window.event) // for IE8
      {
         x=event.keyCode;
      } else if(event.which)//IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari
      {
         x=event.which;
      }
   keychar=String.fromCharCode(x);
   if(keychar == "t" || keychar == "T") {
      alert("Key T was pressed down");
   }
   }

</javascript>
```